# DLL php_http.dll utilizando windows

Tags: php, windows, dll

Existe alguma possibilidade de importar essa DLL -> php_http com o windows? Já utilizei todas as dicas da internet para tentar fazer essa importação, muitas dessas dicas indicam um link que não existe mais: https://downloads.php.net/pierre/ (e que parece ser o único que funciona), todos os outros downloads encontrados após colocar a dll dentro da pasta ext do php e inserir ela nos extensions dentro do php.ini ao restartar o apache apresentam erros dizendo que faltam outras dlls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A biblioteca `php_http` está desatualizada há mais de 6 anos. É incompatível com versões do PHP lançadas desde então.
Recomenda-se o uso da biblioteca [CURL](http://php.net/curl).